# .htaccess rewrite rule preventing infinite loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have a directory named *dollars* that contains a file *index.php*. I would like for the url *http://localhost/dollars/foo* to translate to *dollars/index.php?dollars=foo*. This is the .htaccess file that I currently have in the *dollars* directorty:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?dollars=$1 [L]
```

The idea being that any request other than a request to *index.php* should use the RewriteRule.

However, this does not work.

I've been looking for a while trying to figure out how to create the redirect I want, but I don't even know if I'm on the right track. Regex were never my thing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A often-used solution for rewrites is to just check that the path being requested doesn't point to an actual file/directory, and rewrite it if it doesn't - since the rewritten URL will then point to an actual file, no loop occurs.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Perfect! Thank you so much.

However, I'm a bit confused about the following problem, though it doesn't really affect me. The url localhost/dollars/index redirects to index.php, without passing 'index' as the $1 parameter. Why is this?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Amber's answer should get things working for you, but I wanted to address what was going wrong in your specific case. You had the right idea, but `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` actually ends up being a fully qualified path here, so your regular expression should check for `index.php` at the end, not the beginning.

Consequently, you should find that this will work more like you expect:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?dollars=$1
```

Swapping out the `RewriteCond`s for those that Amber mentioned would be less problematic if you added other things to that directory, though, so I'd recommend using that in place of this anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much! I see what I was doing wrong. Though, I prefer Amber's solution because it's a bit cleaner. Also, the question I asked Amber also applies to this solution, for reasons I don't understand. Thoughts?

Comment: You must have MultiViews turned on for that directory, I think.
Try adding `Options -MutliViews` to that `.htaccess` file and see if it behaves correctly.

Comment: Totally right dude. Someday I'll read a book about this...

Thanks again!