# How to prevent second call after rule is applied for mod_rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.server2.com/index.php?action=$1
```

I need to add another redirect, which should work this way:

```
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) index.php [L]
```

so request is not passed to server2, but served in place.

As I understand, if I add this line, .htaccess is called second time and I am redirected to server2.com/index.php.

I hope, there is some sort of switch that I can use to prevent second mod_rewrite call or should I use RewriteCond instead (for example as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3114509/htaccess-rewrite-rule-preventing-infinite-loop))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude the pattern of the second rule in your first rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^app/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.server2.example/index.php?action=$1
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) index.php [L]
```